# What is causes of UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in TypeGraphql?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeerror, typegraphql, unhandled-promise-rejection

I have an issue with my typegraphql code. I couldn't find what is causes this error message.
The code that I shared below is my resolver and mutation which should return a **ProductResponse**:

```
  @Mutation(returns => ProductResponse)
  async addProduct (@Args() { model, title, description, price, images, productCode }: productData):
  Promise<ProductResponse> {
    try {
      const productInstance = new ProductService()
      const resp = await productInstance.add(model, title, description, price, images, productCode)
      return { product: resp }
    } catch (err: any) {
      return { errorMessage: err.message }
    }
  }
```

Below is the **ProductResponse** class for standardizing the response of all mutations and queries:

```
ObjectType()
export class ProductResponse {
  @Field(returns => String, { nullable: true })
  errorMessage?: string

  @Field(returns => Product, { nullable: true })
  product?: Product
}
```

And this is my service which is returns saved data from DB or throws an error:

```
  async add (model: string, title: string, description: string, price: number, images: string, productCode: string) {
    const product = await Product.findOne({ where: { productCode } })
    if (product) {
      throw new Error("Duplicate product")
    }

    const newProduct = await Product.create({ model, title, description, price, images, productCode }).save()

    return newProduct
  }
```

But when I run this code I am encountering an error message below. What am I doing wrong?

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot determine GraphQL output type for 'addProduct' of 'ProductResolver' class. Is the value, that is used as its TS type or explicit type, decorated with a proper decorator, or is it a proper output value?
```

Comment: its a typo mistake or you are missing the `@` before `ObjectType()` ?

Comment: Thank you Jerome. I fixed this issue after posting it. I think you were right about `@`